# IDASolve Error when translating ODE from Matlab to Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I am currently trying to translate some scripts from Matlab to Octave, including an ODE solver. On Matlab the script runs smoothly, but Octave returns:

```
[IDA ERROR]  IDASolve
  At t = 0.00101 and h = 3.8147e-12, the corrector convergence failed repeatedly or with |h| = hmin.
```

To keep things short, I will only post the relevant functions, variables are defined further upstream:

```
% Create a function handle with constant parameters
DissIonWithConstants = @(xx, ab) DissIon(xx, ab, [B_d_f, k_b, j, s_d_f, E_D, R, B_i_f, s_i_f, E_I, Ma_dgl, M_mol_H, rho_d, m_H, t_el, rho_dgl, alpha0, delta0]);

# ode-solver settings
OPTs = odeset('reltol', 1e-12, 'abstol', 1e-16, 'normcontrol', 'on', 'refine', 5);

% Solve the ODE using the function handle
[xx, ab] = ode15s(DissIonWithConstants, x_span, [alpha0, delta0],OPTs);


function dab = DissIon(xx, ab, werte)
    % dab is output
    dab = zeros(2, 1);

    B_d_f = werte(1);
    k = werte(2);
    T = werte(3);
    s_d_f = werte(4);
    E_D = werte(5);
    R_universal = werte(6);
    B_i_f = werte(7);
    s_i_f = werte(8);
    E_I = werte(9);
    Ma = werte(10);
    M_mol_H = werte(11);
    rho_d = werte(12);
    m_H = werte(13);
    T_e = werte(14);
    rho = werte(15);
    alpha_start = werte(16);
    delta_start = werte(17);

    % Ionisation 
    dab(1) = ab(1) * B_i_f * T_e^(s_i_f) * exp(-E_I/(k*T_e)) * ...
             (rho*(ab(2)-ab(1))/M_mol_H - ...
             (ab(2)-ab(1))/(m_H*(1-ab(1))) * ab(1)^2 * rho^2 / M_mol_H * 2.4147 * 10^(-21) * T_e^(-3/2) * exp(E_I/(k*T_e))) * ...
             1 / (Ma * ((R_universal/M_mol_H*T*(1+alpha_start*T_e/T)/(2-delta_start))^(1/2)));

    % Dissociation
    dab(2) = (ab(2)-2*ab(1)+1) * B_d_f * T^(s_d_f) * exp(-E_D/(k*T)) * ...
             (rho*(1-ab(2))/(2*M_mol_H) - ab(2)^2 * rho^2 / (2*rho_d*M_mol_H) * exp(E_D/(k*T))) * ...
             1 / (Ma * ((R_universal/M_mol_H*T*(1+alpha_start*T_e/T)/(2-delta_start))^(1/2)));
end
```

I played with the odeset but couldn't get it running.

Any idea why this won't work in Octave? I tried opimizing with GPT, but that didn't work.

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: They are different languages with different implementations of functions and similar (often overlapping) syntax, there's no real reason to expect identical results for more complicated functionality. I'd advise getting your translation working with a much simpler ODE so you can confirm you have correctly migrated the _syntax_, then deal with the fact you may need different tolerances or settings in the Octave version

Comment: Thank you, I found that one of the variables is calculated in Matlab using vpasolve, but in Octave should be just solve. Sadly the results are completely different, which I assume is part of why the ODE solver doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code leaves a lot to be desired in terms of documentation / self-documenting code, but even so, there are several things that are a bit 'weird' with this code snippet even if one need not have any idea what it's trying to do. I suspect one of two things is happening: either you have things in your workspace that you haven't cleared, and you're using old things without realising it. Or, you are calling the function in the wrong way / wrong arguments somehow (where 'wrong' may also reflect a difference in how you computed them in matlab compared to octave, rather than simply erroneous input).

For one, even if I make up variables to get the code to run, it will not, because your function is called at a point where it was not even defined yet. Note that matlab expects 'script' functions to appear last, but octave expects them to be defined before they're used. So each time you're running this script, you're running the 'old' DissIon function.

There's not much more one can say here, in the absence of any information regarding at least the "type" and dimensions of the variables you're passing.
However, you may find the following techniques helpful to help you debug your problem.

1. use the `debug_on_error` / `debug_on_warning` functions to help you stop at the point where an error/warning is generated and inspect the state of the currently running function.
2. Highly mathematical / equation-driven code like this is extremely hard to debug. Try to split it into logical components with meaningful names, and/or to use functions when relationships are involved (in other words, attempt a functional programming approach than a state-driven one, which can invite errors).
3. Use [tests](https://docs.octave.org/latest/Test-Functions.html) and [assertions](https://docs.octave.org/latest/Test-Functions.html#index-assert) to ensure correctness of your inputs and outputs. These are often a bit tiresome to implement, but make your code a lot more robust when used properly. E.g. you can ensure inputs have the correct range, dimensions, functions fail appropriately for inappropriate inputs, etc.
4. Instead of passing stuff that needs to be destructured in the way you're dealing with "werte", pass a struct directly instead. This way, if you accidentally mess up the positions of the keywords, you won't get a logical error as a result.

Even so, if you 'do' need destructuring assignment in octave, octave supports this via comma-separated-lists, you don't have to do it by hand one by one like that. E.g. Simply collect all the right-hand-side tokens in a cell array (e.g. `C`), and assign it as follows: [a,b,c] = C{:}. (see https://docs.octave.org/latest/Comma_002dSeparated-Lists.html for details, and also the documentation for the `deal` command);

Lastly, keep in mind that, while some functions have the same names, the implementation in octave can be different to matlab, with subtle differences. So it's worth checking the documentation in each case to confirm if they take the same arguments, in the same order, form, and make the same assumptions about their inputs.

In the case of octave, since sources are generally available, it is also sometimes worth to check the source code of the functions you are using (you can find the files relating to those functions using the `which` command). In many cases, the source files contain comments with valuable information regarding the algorithm that is used under the hood, references to academic papers, etc.